# Looking for a better way to validate a date in c# 4

Tags: c#

Wondering if there is a better way to validate A date,

```
  public static bool ValidDate(this  DateTime value)
  {
     if (value == DateTime.MinValue) return false;
     if (value == DateTime.MaxValue) return false;
     var validSqlDate = ((value >= (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MinValue) && (value <= (DateTime)SqlDateTime.MaxValue));
     if (!validSqlDate) return false;
     if (value.Year <= 1900) return false;

     return true;
  }
```

Any suggestions

EDITED Added Rules

- DateTime cannot be empty
- if has value it should be safe to save in to sql server
- I had scenarios where the date were set to 1900.Is this some sort of MinValue

=============

Comment: "Better" in what way? Those look like domain specific rules there.

Comment: What are the validation rules you need?

Comment: Because value is a DateTime it will already be within the valid range for DateTime, so your first two checks are redundant (unless you really want to reject dates that are on the boundaries).

Comment: ShellShock, the OP wants to consider DateTime.MinValue and DateTime.MaxValue invalid, although they are valid values of DateTime.

Comment: I added the rules in my question.@Florian min and max c# and not the same in sql server is that correct or missing the obvious.Edited the question with rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *better way* is to write just the amount of code you need to fulfill your goal.

DateTime.MinValue is `1/1/0001`. SqlDateTime.MinValue is `1/1/1753`. Later, you reject all years below 1900. As such, the checks on the `MinValue` fields are redundant, get rid of them.

DateTime.MaxValue and SqlDateTime.MaxValue are the same thing. You do not need both checks, drop the SqlDateTime comparison.

So ultimately, your function is `return value.Year > 1900 && value < DateTime.MaxValue;` Is accepting all dates from January 1, 1901 through December 31, 9999 your business goal?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Makes sense.And yes my business goal is to accept valid Dates as you described